# Searching AD for email addresses by Organizational Unit

Tags: perl, active-directory

I have a Perl script that is meant to search AD for email addresses.

[I used this script from here](https://www.itefix.no/i2/content/extracting-e-mail-addresses-active-directory) however I'd like to modify it to search a specific org unit for all email addresses ending in .com, rather than scraping all email addresses in general.

Note: I have zero Perl experience, I usually only do Python but can't figure it out in Python, Googled how to do it in Perl and got an instant result that worked.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Changing this line would give you email addresses @domain.com - if that is what you need!

```
my @adrlist = ($line =~ /smtp:(\w+\@domain.com)\;/g);
```

Comment: yes, that is what I need, thank you!!! After days of Googling, trying to do this in Python, thank you!!!